# Open Graph API Limits

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our app uses FaceBook profiles along with their publicly available data.
Today we use the following API:

```
         https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=[id1,id2,...,idN]
```

We use this API with the FaceBook profile IDs we get from our subscribers.
I wonder if FaceBook will block us if we will use this API extensively?

Is there any limit that you are aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook make the following statement about API limits in their [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

"If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact us as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (**>100M API calls per day**) or (>50M impressions per day)."

Comment: Hi Cormac, you mentioned the 100M API calls per day in bold, is that the relevant limit to my question?

Comment: I believe so, because you were asking about API usage limits.

Comment: Those limits are a policy limit above which you need contracts with Facebook, the actual limits are dynamic, per-user, and based on both CPU usage and call rate, there's nothing inherent in that specific example call which would be 'bad' though, unless it's being called over and over again

Comment: Hi Igy, Assuming I am only using the simple API I mentioned above, and do not have any contract with FaceBook will I have different limit than 100M /day?